# Transparent Material in Swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tvos

I'm working on a tvOS (v15) app in SwiftUI, but this question may also apply to iOS, watchOS and macOS.

When creating a custom focusable view from `Text` I want its background to remain absolutely transparent by default and when focus, take advantage of SwiftUI 3.0 ability to assign translucent material on the background. The code works fine, but I can't seem to find a way of making `Material` transparent.

Consider this example:

```
//I want to able to set this to transparent by default instead of setting a ".regular" material (which is opaque)
@State private var plotBackground: Material = .regular 

@FocusState private var elementFocused: Bool

[...]
Text("Lorem Ipsum ...")
    .padding()
    .focusable()
    .focused($elementFocused)
    .onChange(of: elementFocused) { isFocused in
        withAnimation {
           self.plotBackground = isFocused ? .ultraThin : .regular
        }
    }
    .background(plotBackground, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess transparent Material is the equivalent of no Material, so
try using an optional: `@State private var plotBackground: Material? = nil`
 and deal with the optional/unwrapping.